# Filter results matching single character in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

In my elastic search results, results are given even it matches a single character. results look weird when we see results with single digits.

Is there anyway to filter out results matching single digit/character through DSL query.

current query:

```
GET /attachment_index/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "user_email_id",
    "file_content_id",
    "file_name",
    "non_indexed_meta_data"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "user_email_id",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "user_email_id": "test@user.com"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "attachment.content": {
              "query": "mark twain 3",
              "analyzer": "english", 
              "operator": "or"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "order": "score",
    "pre_tags": [
      "<strong>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</strong>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "attachment.content": {}
    }
  },
  "size": 100
}
```

it is giving results matches for 3 which i don't want. any thoughts on filtering on length without preprocessing before feeding to elastic search ?

Comment: You don't want any numbers?

Comment: as it is doing or search, don't want to single char values

Comment: is there a way to filter based on length?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to filter based on length using a custom analyzer. [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) contains an example how to rebuild the English analyzer so we can add the minimum length filter there, e.g.

```
PUT /attachment_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_english_"
        },
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "english"
        },
        "english_possessive_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "possessive_english"
        },
        "length": {
          "type": "length",
          "min": 2
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "length_english": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop",
            "english_stemmer",
            "length"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To try this:

```
GET attachment_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "length_english",
  "text": "mark twain 3"
}
```

returns

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "mark",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "twain",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

so `3` got filtered out as desired. Analyzer `length_english` can be used instead of `english` in match query.

Comment: It filters indexing. I believe OP is asking about single character in the search term. Good one regardless.

Comment: It depends how the custom analyzer is used. Match query takes analyzer as a parameter so this can be used to analyze the search text. It could be used for the field as well, then it would filter when indexing.

Comment: That's the answer then. Good one. Custom analyzer at query time.